# PBR reflection stange behaviour

Tags: opengl, pbr

I've implemented a PBR rendered using OpenGL in my deferred rendering engine.
The problem is that there are strange signs on my object as the roughness increases.

You can see this on these images:

[image]
[image]

I've found out that the problem is with the filtering. Using LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR gives the results shown above, but when I use NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR the strange seams aren't present but when the surface is more rough you can see the pixels of the texture (as you can see on the image below).

[image]

Comment: I'm no expert but that could be related to cubemap seam.  I remember reading about it on Castano's blog. http://the-witness.net/news/2012/02/seamless-cube-map-filtering/

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem. Enabling `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS` resolved my problem. A little bit of seams are still visible when the material is really rough, but it's acceptable. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

As Robinson mentioned in his comment, reading the article he posted showed me the answer: i just needed to enable GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_SEAMLESS on my cubemap texture.